# Prime divides $n^2 + 1 \Rightarrow$ prime doesn't divide $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

How can I show that if a prime $p$ divides $$n^2 + 1$$ then it doesn't divide $n$?

Comment: If p divides n then it must divide n^2. No number other than 1 can divide two consecutive numbers.

Comment: Dang auto correct.  And that was a *weird* one.  Can not understand it.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive, it's easier to think about.

Comment: Lol thanks for the explanation, I can't believe I didn't think of that

Comment: @fleablood Maybe cutie numbers are like friendly numbers and lucky numbers at the same time?

Comment: I was actually surprised as I typed the answer.  I thought it'd be one of those "since p is prime if it divides such it must divide that..." type things.  Actually no need for p to be prime.  Just not one.

Comment: Applying Euclid's algorithm $\,(n^k\!+1,n) = (1,n) = 1\,$ by $\,n^k\!+1\equiv 1\pmod n\,$ for $\,k\ge 1.\,$ Since their gcd $= 1,\,$ they have no nontrivial common divisor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) to show that $\left(n^2+1,n\right)=1$. That is,
$$
\left(n^2+1\right)\cdot1-n\cdot n=1
$$
Therefore, the greatest common divisor of $n^2+1$ and $n$ is $1$.

That is, if any number divided both $n^2+1$ and $n$, it would also divide $(n^2+1)-n\cdot n=1$.

Comment: For every integer $k\ge 1$, $(n^k+1)\cdot 1-n\cdot n^{k-1}=1$.

Comment: Indeed. $\left(n^k+1,n\right)=1$ for $k\ge1$.

Comment: @Woria Special case $\, j = n^{k-1}\,$ of  $\,(1\!+\!nj,\,n) = 1\ $ by $\ 1= 1\!+\!nj-n(j)\ \ $ (or by one step of Euclid's algorithm - see my comment on the question).

Answer (score 5):

A proof by contradiction: assume $n\equiv 0\mod p$ with $p>1$, then $$n^2\equiv 0\pmod p$$ also. But $$n^2\equiv -1\pmod p$$ which contradicts, therefore
$$n^2+1\equiv 0\pmod p\Rightarrow n\not\equiv 0\pmod p$$

Comment: i.e. if $\,p\mid n,\color{#c00}{n^2\!+\!1}\,$ then $\,{\rm mod}\ p\!:\  n\equiv 0\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv \color{#c00}{n^2\equiv -1}\,\Rightarrow\, p\mid 1,\,$ contradiction

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Below, all 'leters variables' $\ds{n,s,p}$ are integers
>   $\ds{\pars{~p\ \mbox{is a}\ \ul{prime\ number}~}}$:

- $\ds{{n \over p} = s\quad\imp\quad n = sp\quad\imp\quad{n^{2} + 1 \over p} =
  {s^{2}p^{2} + 1 \over p} = s^{2} p + {1 \over p}\ !!!}$

  ---
- $\ds{{1 \over p}\ \ul{\mbox{is not}}\ \mbox{an integer because}\ p > 1
  \pars{~p\ \mbox{is a prime number}~}}$

  ---
- $\pars{\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
  p \mid n \imp p \not\mid \pars{n^{2} + 1}}\ \mbox{is equivalent to}\
  \pars{\vphantom{\LARGE A}%
  p \mid \pars{n^{2} + 1} \imp p \not\mid n}$

Answer (score 1):

If $p=2
 $ and $2\mid n
 $ we have that $n^{2}
 $ is even and so $n^{2}+1
 $ is odd. Now assume that $p$ is odd. We can use the Legendre symbol. If we assume that $n\equiv0\mod p
 $ we have $n^{2}\equiv0 \mod p
 $. So $$\left(\frac{n^{2}}{p}\right)=0
 $$ but since $n^{2}\equiv-1 \mod p$ we also have, by the law of quadratic reciprocity $$\left(\frac{n^{2}}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)=1^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\begin{cases}
1 & p\equiv1\,\mod\,4\\
-1 & p\equiv3\,\mod\,4
\end{cases}$$ and this is absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You want to prove the statement $\color\red{p|n^2+1}\implies\color\green{p\not|n}$.

Instead, you can prove the equivalent statement $\neg(\color\green{p\not|n})\implies\neg(\color\red{p|n^2+1})$:

$\small\neg(\color\green{p\not|n})\implies{p|n}\implies{p|n^2}\implies{\forall_{k\in(0,p)}:p\not|n^2+k}\implies{p\not|n^2+1}\implies\neg(\color\red{p|n^2+1})$.

BTW, this statement holds not only for every prime $p$, but also for every integer $p>1$.